# How to pass data from twig to Symfony2 controller using form

Tags: symfony, controller, twig

I would like to know if there is a method to pass some variables (text from textarea) from Twig to Symfony2 controller via form.

```
        <form action="{{ path('admin_core_save') }}" method="post">
            <div id="edit-template">
                {% if template.getData() is defined %}
                    <textarea id="template">{{ template.getData() }}</textarea>
                {% endif %}
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
```

When I press save button it is going to saveAction() method

```
public function saveAction(Request $request)
{
    var_dump($request);

    return new Response('abc');
}
```

but response does not contain any textarea text. Is there a way to get this there?

I know I can build form inside the controller and send it to Twig, but I would like to know if this way is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access POST values through request object like:

```
$this->get('request')->request->get('name');
```

Comment: that made the trick, i forgot I need to put name="abc" in my textarea! Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you have to learn a bit about **[Symfony2 Form Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)**. You will find that symfony already has built-in system for rendering forms handling user data posted through them.

Answering your question. There is a **[Request](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html)** object that provides you full access to all request data, including POST variables.

To access POST values use [Request::get()](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_get) method:

```
$request->get('variable_name');
```

To pass any data to the twig template, use [TwigEngine::renderResponse](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/TwigEngine.html#method_renderResponse)

```
$this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:template.twig,html',
    array(
        'someVar' => 'some value'
    )
);
```

This var will be avaliable in your template as:

```
{{ someVar }}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It also works! I can finally get my variable_name in the controller.

Comment: @GrzegorzTomasiak if it helped you, please, accept the right answer.